# Time complexity optimisation of a "nested for loop" method

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to find the largest differences between indexes of two equal elements, in an zero-index array of integers.

My for loop currently looks like this, with a "nested for loops" structure
which means its time complexity is O(N^2).

### Is it possible of reducing its time complexity to O(N * log(N)) or lower?

```
public static Integer solution(Integer[] arr) {
    Integer l = arr.length;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                result = Math.max(result, Math.abs(i - j));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Possibly belongs in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to find the highest difference of two indexes of equal numbers in an array. You don't need to run through the entire array 2 times. The inner loop can simply end at `i` which will greatly reduce complexity.

```
public static int solution(int[] arr) {
  int l = arr.length;
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
        result = Math.max(result, Math.abs(i - j));
    }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The complexity should just about be O(N * log(N)).

Comment: Well, simple and effective. Thank you for sharing your code.

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider to upvote and mark it as the answer to your question